# Haskell non-exhaustive patterns in function with `otherwise`

Tags: haskell, combinations, non-exhaustive-patterns

I am using the following function:

```
combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combinations k xs = combinations' (length xs) k xs
  where combinations' n k' l@(y:ys)
          | k' == 0   = [[]]
          | k' >= n   = [l]
          | null l    = []
          | otherwise = Prelude.map (y :) (combinations' (n - 1) (k' - 1) ys) ++ combinations' (n - 1) k' ys
```

It works just fine for just about any example i can come up with, but when i call it from other functions in my larger project, for some cases I get an exception:

```
Exception: projekt.hs:(34,9)-(38,108): Non-exhaustive patterns in function combinations'
```

Is there something wrong with the above definition? Is it missing some case? I thought `otherwise` handles anything that doesn't fall into previous cases.

Comment: `otherwise` handles anything that doesn't fall into previous _guards_ -- but doesn't make a pattern match support other _cases_.

Comment: you could fix this with a very small edit, by changing `l@(y:ys)` to `l@ ~(y:ys)`, making the pattern lazy, and so irrefutable (so empty lists are accepted too). I would recommend against such a style though, it makes the code too fragile and non-apparent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of `l@(x:xs)` in `combinations' n k' l@(y:ys)` you're missing the case `combinations _ _ []`.

The guard `null l` will always be `False`.